# Type mismatch when creating DataTable in google charts

Tags: javascript, python, datetime, google-visualization

I have a list of lists of unix timestamp, value. Like this:

```
stream = [[1485936060000, 268623], [1485936180000, 268624], [1485936300000, 268626]]
```

I want to create a line google chart in which the unix timestamps will be visible as real dates. I tried iterating through the stream array and converting them all to a Date object, but it didn't really work. It threw this exception:

```
Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value Wed Feb 01 2017 09:01:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time) does not match type number in column index 0
```

Bellow is the full code of the function:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

var stream = {{ stream }}
var maximum = {{ maximum }}
var minimum = {{ minimum }}
var unit = {{ unitlabel }}


function drawChart() {

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(stream);
  data.addColumn('number', 'Timestamp');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Actual value');

  for ( var i = 0; i < stream.length; i++ ) {
    var d = new Date(+stream[i][0]);
    stream[i][0] = d;
}

data.addRows(stream);


  var options = {
  width: 1500,
  height: 500,
  isStacked: false,
   axes: {
        y: {
            all: {
                kWh: {label: 'kWh'},
                format: { pattern: 'decimal'},
                range: {
                    max: maximum,
                    min: minimum
                }
            },

        }
    },
    };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Help?

Comment: change your column data type 
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Timestamp');

Answer (score 0):

You have to set proper data types for the column. Like error says you are trying to fit 'datetime' in 'number'

change your column data type

data.addColumn('datetime', 'Timestamp');